# Accord en nombre d'une énumération contractée

Tags: grammaire, accord, énumération

Petite question de grammaire.

Dans la phrase suivante :

> La structure du schéma de données et du code ont été modifiées

**Modifier** est ici conjugué au passé composé à la voix passive.
**La structure du schéma de données et du code** sous-entend **la structure du schéma de données et la structure du code**, il s'agit de deux éléments distincts, donc bien une énumération, même si ces deux structures, dans la pratique, vont ensembles et ne sauraient être séparées.

Ma question est : doit-on, grammaticalement parlant, accorder "modifiée" au singulier ou au pluriel dans la phrase ci-dessus?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

J'écrirais soit :

> **La** structure (du schéma de données et du code) **a** été modifiée.

soit :

> **Les** structures du schéma de données **et** du code **ont** été modifiées.

Dans le premier cas, on considère qu'il n'y a qu'une structure, ou du moins que les deux structures peuvent être confondues tandis que dans le deuxième cas, il n'y a pas de lien entre les structures modifiées. Le sujet dois alors être au pluriel puisqu'il n'est pas répété.

Suite aux commentaires, quelques variantes :

> **La** structure du schéma de données **et la** structure du code **ont** été modifiées.
>
> **La** structure du schéma de données **et celle** du code **ont** été modifiées.
>
> **La** structure du schéma de données **comme celle** du code **ont** été modifiées.<sup>1</sup>
>
> **La** structure du schéma de données, **comme celle** du code, **a** été modifiée.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>comme introduit une addition : *ainsi que*</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>comme introduit une comparaison : *de la même manière que*</sub>

Comment: C'est en sous-texte de ma question : je ne sais pas si il y en a une qui est correcte et l'autre non, c'est mon problème.

Comment: ou encore: la structure ... et la structure ... ont été modifiées ... ou la structure ... et celle ... ont été modifiées ...

Comment: Merci pour la réponse, ça m'aide à y voir plus clair.